# Interval to previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the interval between the rows in my table.

When I use this query I get seconds from previous timestamp.
But the result is only right when two timestamps is in the same minute.

```
SELECT 
    Time_Stamp, 
    State,
    Time_Stamp - LAG(Time_Stamp) OVER(ORDER BY Time_Stamp)
AS Seconds_In_State
FROM State_Table
ORDER BY Time_Stamp;
```

How do I get the result in intervals?

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Comment: Your code is basically correct.  You are probably misinterpreting the results.

Comment: I am using MySQL.
Time_Stamp 03:56 to Time_Stamp 04:30 the result is 74.  [430-356 =74] 
So I can not do this with DATETIME datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `timestampdiff()` function. I have used minute as unit here.

The unit should be one of the following : FRAC_SECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR. Unit is the measurement unit here in which you want to count the difference.

```
SELECT 
    Time_Stamp, 
    State,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, LAG(Time_Stamp) OVER(ORDER BY Time_Stamp),Time_Stamp)
AS Minute_In_State
FROM State_Table
ORDER BY Time_Stamp;
```

Comment: Thanks Kazi, that was very useful... :-)